# riverpod: Does someone know a pattern for dealing with loading AsyncValue inside an StreamProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

The question is what to return in case `aStreamProvider` is loading. The returned needs to be a `Stream`, but actually the code needs to wait and send nothing until `aStreamProvider` is loaded (bc it is needed to `compute_something`)

```
final aStreamProvider = StreamProvider((ref) => Stream.empty()); // just an example - imagine something complicated
final bStreamProvider = StreamProvider<int>((ref) {
  final myAsyncValue = ref.watch(aStreamProvider);
  return myAsyncValue.when(data: compute_something,
  loading: what_to_do_here,
  error: (_, __) => throw Exception());
}
```

thx

Comment: have you tried ```aStreamProvider.listen``` method?

Comment: no - but, at least in my code completion, there is no `listen` method on my `StreamProvider`
Edit: to be fair, I am using a `StreamProvider.family`

Comment: do you maybe mean `ref.listen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `AsyncValue.loading()`, since effectively while the inner stream is loading, so are you.

Comment: nice - this sounds good

Comment: hey - any chance you could show an example please - i have not figured it out yet - thx
(i could not get the types to match)

Comment: Also, can the same concept be applied inside a Provider (and not a StreamProvider)?

Comment: sry, I undid the 'correct answer' bc I cannot get the types to match, i.e. your solution to work

Comment: You need all the return types to be variants of AsyncValue.  AsyncValue.loading(), AsyncValue.data(...) and AsyncValue.error(...).

Comment: Is this also possible with a `Provider` instead of `StreamProvider`?